# Difficulty mapping JSON file. (NextJS, Typescript)

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, next.js

I'm very new to JS and trying to understand how to map the content of a json file to html elements.

When I run on the dev server, I get the following error: **"props.books.map is not a function"**.

My intuitive guess is that the way my json file is formatted, doesn't align with the way .map needs it to be. (I'm not entirely sure what static json files are supposed to look like. I keep seeing different examples online, so if anyone has resources to what industry standard json files are supposed to look like that would be great!)

Here's a snippet of my json file.

[./static/bookReviews.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0Sx3.png)

Here's the code for the file that attempts to map the json file.

*./pages/content/books.tsx*

```
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import { NextPage, GetStaticProps } from "next";

const Books: NextPage<{
  books: {
    author: string;
    dateFinish: string;
    dateStart: string;
    rating: string;
    review: string;
    title: string;
  }[];
}> = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="justify-between items-center bg-gradient-to-b from-slate-600 to-slate-900 p-10 w-screen h-screen">
      <NavBar />
      <h1>Books</h1>
      

      {props.books.map((x) => {
        return <p>{x.title}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async () => {
  const books = (await import("../../static/bookReviews.json")).default;

  return {
    props: { books },
  };
};

export default Books;
```

Please let me know if any further information is needed to understand this issue.

Any help is much appreciated :)

Comment: `XXX.map is not a function` is generally because XXX is not an array.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code? Logged to the console? Make sure the JSON is being loaded and parsed correctly

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out!
When I imported the json file, I didn't specify the Books component. If you look at the json file, the key is "Books" and its value is an array of dictionaries that contain book information. So once I specified the array, the .map function functioned properly.

The change I made was

```
  const books = ((await import("../../static/bookReviews.json")).Books);
```

Thank you [@crashmstr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1441/crashmstr) for pointing me in the right direction!